# Unable in adding initial monitor to Ceph in Ubuntu

Tags: ceph

I am trying to set up a Ceph cluster. I have 4 nodes - 1 admin-node, 1 monitor and 2 object storage devices. The installation guide I am using is given at the following location:
http://ceph.com/docs/master/start/quick-ceph-deploy/.

When I am trying to add the initial monitor (step 5 in the guide), I am getting the following error:

```
[ceph_deploy.conf][DEBUG ] found configuration file at: /home/cloud-user/.cephdeploy.conf
[ceph_deploy.cli][INFO  ] Invoked (1.5.21): /usr/bin/ceph-deploy mon create-initial
[ceph_deploy.mon][DEBUG ] Deploying mon, cluster ceph hosts worker-1-full
[ceph_deploy.mon][DEBUG ] detecting platform for host worker-1-full ...
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] connected to host: worker-1-full 
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] detect platform information from remote host
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] detect machine type
[ceph_deploy.mon][INFO  ] distro info: Ubuntu 14.04 trusty
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] determining if provided host has same hostname in remote
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] get remote short hostname
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] deploying mon to worker-1-full
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] get remote short hostname
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] remote hostname: worker-1-full
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] write cluster configuration to /etc/ceph/{cluster}.conf
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] create the mon path if it does not exist
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] checking for done path: /var/lib/ceph/mon/ceph-worker-1-full/done
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] create a done file to avoid re-doing the mon deployment
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] create the init path if it does not exist
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] locating the `service` executable...
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo initctl emit ceph-mon cluster=ceph id=worker-1-full
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[worker-1-full][WARNIN] monitor: mon.worker-1-full, might not be running yet
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[worker-1-full][WARNIN] monitor worker-1-full does not exist in monmap
[worker-1-full][WARNIN] neither `public_addr` nor `public_network` keys are defined for monitors
[worker-1-full][WARNIN] monitors may not be able to form quorum
[ceph_deploy.mon][INFO  ] processing monitor mon.worker-1-full
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] connection detected need for sudo
[worker-1-full][DEBUG ] connected to host: worker-1-full 
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] mon.worker-1-full monitor is not yet in quorum, tries left: 5
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] waiting 5 seconds before retrying
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] mon.worker-1-full monitor is not yet in quorum, tries left: 4
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] waiting 10 seconds before retrying
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] mon.worker-1-full monitor is not yet in quorum, tries left: 3
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] waiting 10 seconds before retrying
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] mon.worker-1-full monitor is not yet in quorum, tries left: 2
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] waiting 15 seconds before retrying
[worker-1-full][INFO  ] Running command: sudo ceph --cluster=ceph --admin-daemon /var/run/ceph/ceph-mon.worker-1-full.asok mon_status
[worker-1-full][ERROR ] admin_socket: exception getting command descriptions: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] mon.worker-1-full monitor is not yet in quorum, tries left: 1
[ceph_deploy.mon][WARNIN] waiting 20 seconds before retrying
[ceph_deploy.mon][ERROR ] Some monitors have still not reached quorum:
[ceph_deploy.mon][ERROR ] worker-1-full
```

"worker-1-full" is the node I am trying to set up as my monitor. The command I used is:

"ceph-deploy mon create-initial". Please help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This isn't a programming question and should probably be asked in a different forum such as a serverfault.

Comment: serverfault is indeed a better place to ask this question

Answer (score 1):

Please check your ceph-deploy version:
ceph-deploy --version

I met same problem on 1.5.30,
see http://docs.ceph.com/ceph-deploy/docs/changelog.html#id34,
Default to the "infernalis" release.

use 1.5.29 ceph-deploy and "hammer" release , it's work fine. 
(perhaps other combination also ok.)

Good luck ~~